# How do I default a Library view to the current Month

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to:

1. Default a Library View to the Current Month
2. When someone adds a document to the library a field called Month (text field) would always default to the current month (December, January, etc.)

Currently every month I do the following:

- I go to the view and change the month to the current month
- I go to the default value settings and change the default value for the field called Month to the current month

I would love to avoid this manual monthly updates

Answer (score 0):

For both put this formula to get the current month in the SharePoint.

```
=TEXT([Today],"MMMM")
```

This will automatically take the month of today's date that is current month

Note :-  As mentioned in question if you want Month column to be text field which can be changed later manually then this would work for the column or else you have to use calculated column and put formula as `=TEXT([Created],"MMMM")`

Comment: when item is modified or formula is recalculated it will always default month of today's date which is not correct..right ?

Comment: As @daPlayaURH told its a text field so setting default value will change only while adding so there wont be any issue with this while modifying. but if this formula is put in the calculated field then only the issue will raise. it can also be achieved by  calculated column as = Text([Created], 'MMMM'), i have added note in my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Update formula of Month as  calculated column with below formula.

```
   = MONTH([Created] // this will month in numeric like 1,3,4,5
```

OR

```
=TEXT([Today],"MMM") // this will give month in text like jan, feb, apr, jul
```

OR

```
=TEXT([Today],"MMMM") // this will give month in text like January, April, July, August
```

This will make sure that a column will always have month of day on which item is created.

Note - Issue with above Raghvendra answer is that when item is modified or formula is recalculated it will always default month of today's date which is not correct.